# Access Specific Elements in a Matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I'm new in Python and my problem involves getting specific elements in a matrix and create a new matrix with these elements. Here's my attempt to do it.

```
import numpy as np

a = [[  1,   2,   3, 4, 5],
 [  6,   7,   8, 9, 10],
 [  11,  12,  13, 14, 15],
 [  16,   17, 18, 19, 20],
 [  21,   22, 23, 24, 25]]

b = np.array(a)
```

I want to get only the 1st and 3rd column of this matrix then combine them to create a new matrix. I tried adding this code below:

```
newList = []

for i in range(len(b-1)):
    newList.append(b[i,0])+ newList.append(b[i,2])
```

But I got the following error instead:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: If you want the diagonal elements of `b`, you should use `b.diagonal()`.

Comment: See also [`numpy.nditer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html)

Comment: Hi @Evert, this is just an example. I'm actually interested in getting specific columns of a matrix.  For example, I have a 5 x 5 matrix but I only want to use the 1st and 3rd column then combine it into a new matrix.

Comment: Add the specific code to the question. The question doesn't give any hint about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can you use [`diagonal()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) for your initial question:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix([[1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ],
               [6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10],
               [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
               [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
               [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])

print(a.diagonal())
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 1  7 13 19 25]]
```

As for your question in the comments you can combine the first and third columns like so:

```
first_column = (a[:,0]) 
third_column = (a[:,2])

print(first_column + third_column)
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 4]
 [14]
 [24]
 [34]
 [44]]
```

Since you now want a row simply call [transpose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html):

```
print((first_column + third_column).transpose())
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 4 14 24 34 44]]
```

Comment: Sorry. This is my expected output [[ 1, 3]
 [6, 8]
 [11, 13]
 [16, 18]
 [21, 23]].

Comment: There you go :) consider looking at the numpy documentation its very easy to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using your input:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[  1,   2,   3, 4, 5],
 [  6,   7,   8, 9, 10],
 [  11,  12,  13, 14, 15],
 [  16,   17, 18, 19, 20],
 [  21,   22, 23, 24, 25]]

b = np.array(a)

col_1=b[:,0] #Slicing first column
col_3=b[:,2] #Slicing third column

new_mat=np.matrix([col_1,col_3]) #Creates a matrix with col_1 as 1st row and col_3 as second row
new_mat=np.transpose(new_mat)
```

**Output:**

```
matrix([[ 1,  3],
        [ 6,  8],
        [11, 13],
        [16, 18],
        [21, 23]])
```

Hope this helps